# Why is my custom React Context not working with this third party library (Tone.js)

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, web-audio-api, react-context, tone.js

I'm in the process of refactoring an old project and am trying to use only functional components, hooks, etc. The project is a step sequencer (i.e. an application that lets you create your own musical loops/vamps by toggling a grid of buttons).

I want to abstract all the WebAudio logic into a separate file. I've created a React Context that mimics everything done in the class component and exposes the necessary data/functions via the `useContext` hook, but for some reason, the version utilizing functional components and hooks is unable to interface with Tone.js.

[**I've created a CodeSandbox**](https://codesandbox.io/s/step-sequencer-h6yrv?file=/src/App.js) where you can easily toggle between the Class and Functional versions so you can see what I'm talking about.

I wish I could be more specific as to what's not working, but I honestly have no idea why everything is broken. I think I'm getting confused because Tone.js is an event-driven framework and it's difficult to switch between that mode of thinking and the declarative model used in React.

[**Tone.js documentation**](https://tonejs.github.io/docs/14.7.77/index.html)

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: i messed around with the sandbox demo, and honestly couldn't find anything really broken, but i suspect any issues may be solved by either waiting until the `Tone.start()`/`Tone.loaded()` promise is resolved before triggering sampler notes, or wrapping those trigger invocations with a good old `useCallback` (while properly picking the desired dependencies). here's how i'm getting it to work in [my (very similar) project](https://github.com/eliranmal/drifter) ([website](https://eliranmal.github.io/drifter/)), though i have no use of `React.context()`, which seems to be the crux here